Serverless Bref CLI laravel migrate command returning The command exited with a non-zero status code: 1
I have bref installed for my laravel api, it has been deployed successfully, but when I run

serverless bref:cli --args="migrate --force"

to migrate my tables in the database, I get the error

The command exited with a non-zero status code: 1"

This is the full stacktrace

lluminate\Foundation\Application::handleCommand(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))
857c1f7c-9beb-4f72-9ed4-a9d6ee1a878b    Invoke Error    {"errorType":"Exception","errorMessage":"The command exited with a non-zero status code: 1","stack":["#0 /var/task/vendor/bref/bref/src/Runtime/Invoker.php(29): Bref\ConsoleRuntime\Main::Bref\ConsoleRuntime\{closure}('migrate --force', Object(Bref\Context\Context))","#1 /var/task/vendor/bref/bref/src/Runtime/LambdaRuntime.php(94): Bref\Runtime\Invoker->invoke(Object(Closure), 'migrate --force', Object(Bref\Context\Context))","#2 /var/task/vendor/bref/bref/src/ConsoleRuntime/Main.php(36): Bref\Runtime\LambdaRuntime->processNextEvent(Object(Closure))","#3 /opt/bref/bootstrap.php(17): Bref\ConsoleRuntime\Main::run()","#4 {main}"]}

Here is my serverless.yml database configuration
provider:
name: aws
# The AWS region in which to deploy (us-east-1 is the default)
region: us-east-1
# Environment variables
runtime: provided.al2
environment:
    APP_ENV: production # Or use ${sls:stage} if you want the environment to match the stage
    APP_DEBUG: true # set to false when moving to production
    LOG_CHANNEL: stderr # this will send logs to CloudWatch automatically
    SESSION_DRIVER: database # to avoid writing sessions to disk
    VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp/storage/framework/views
    DB_CONNECTION: pgsql
    DB_HOST: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com
    DB_PORT: 5432
    DB_DATABASE: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    DB_USERNAME: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    DB_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
    - sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    subnetIds:
    - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    - subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


you will need to find the errors that caused the underlying command to exit with a status code of 1. There may be something in the logs

This is the error that I am getting.
[2024-05-16 14:53:28] production.ERROR: could not find driver (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select c.relname as name, n.nspname as schema, pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) as size, obj_description(c.oid, 'pg_class') as comment ...
So I guess psql is not a valid driver for postgresql on bref, funny thing is, that is what I know and have been using on laravel.

I have not found a way to enable or install PDO extension on Amazon RDS postgresql

https://bref.sh/docs/environment/php mentions that the pdo pgsql extension is disabled but is there so you could enable it
